# What is the native way to communicate with a standard USB PTP/MTP camera on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, usb

I'm looking at WinUsb, and I have a feeling it's not what I need. Could you please point me in the right direction?

I just need to detect device and send/receive raw data. I used to use libusb, but some of it's characteristic force me to switch to a native API. The only problem is I don't know it's name.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've got some answers here:
https://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=HKEDKEEGPPEOHLHHEPEDKEOADBAA.michael.plante%40gmail.com&forum_name=libusb-win32-devel

In a few words - WPD for Windows Vista/7 and ReadFile/WriteFile for XP.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're looking for [WPD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463541) (Windows Portable Devices). This API is included in the Windows SDK and supports MTP communication with a variety of devices. The WPD team have a very useful [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpdblog/), which contains [instructions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpdblog/archive/2007/04/01/downloading-wpd-for-development.aspx) on how to get started with development.

Edit:

If you want raw USB access then WPD has a [driver kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff597868.aspx) available:

> **Windows Portable Devices Driver Kit**
>   The WPD Driver Kit includes a
>   Device Driver Interface (DDI) that is supported in Windows 7, Windows
>   Vista, and Windows XP operating Systems. Developers will use this DDI
>   to write drivers for devices that are not already supported by the MTP
>   or Mass Storage class drivers that Microsoft distributes.

Comment: Thank you very much. If it allows to send/receive raw data - this is it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it won't help because WPD requires app developer to make too many moves to detect devices on Win XP. Too bad...

Comment: No-no-no, that was a bad idea - looks like WPD doesn't support raw USB bulk transfers :(

Comment: If you want raw USB then you're probably looking at a user-mode driver. What is it you can't do over MTP?

Comment: I can't support non-standard vendor-specific commands, for that I need to handle packets myself. User-mode driver? Never heard of it, but it definitely doesn't sound encouraging...

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it. I have a device that works under standard Microsoft driver, and I need to manually read/write raw data to it. I need libusb functionality, only with native Windows API. I've found I can open device with CreateFile and then use WriteFile/ReadFile. But I don't see how to get a list of endpoints and perform I/O on a specific endpoint. Any suggestions?